# Too many 2 way data bindings issue in angular.js - workaround

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, long-polling

We've got a `<table>` of data which live syncs between users in a similar way to Google Spreadsheets, for this we are using Angular.js and syncing the data using long polling (not the most scalable but for our needs - private web app with set limit of users this is fine).

The table has a mixture of static generated values, inputs, checkboxes, select elements in the cells.

The user is able to sort, filter and scroll through the table / columns.

The `<table>` has about 26 columns and can have up to 500 rows so that could be 13000 (26*500) elements which need to be synced back and forth, after about 1500 elements we've found angular takes a) ages to render the table and b) when data is synced it becomes un responsive.

Apart from the obvious (have less elements) which is not an option from a UX point of view as all the data needs to be displayed to the user, is there a prescribed work around for this ? Am I using the right tool for the job with angular ?

I was playing with the idea of :

A) Making all the data 'read sync only' (so it would get updated, but wouldn't constantly push updates) instead of read + write sync so it was only 1 way and only make an element 2 way when its clicked on ie. when you click on an input it would become a 2 way element, and when your done it would go back to read sync only.

B) Implementing a kind of infinite scroll pagination - that would say load 20 rows and a time as you scrolled down it would unload the first 20 rows and add the next 20, you could then scroll back up if needed and it would reload the first 20 and unload the second 20. My only concern with this is that it might be complex to implement and also im not sure how it would work with the filtering and sorting.

Are either of these approached applicable to overcoming 2 way data binding limits - or is there another approach ive overlooked ?

Comment: I would recommend you look at this: http://kamilkp.github.io/angular-vs-repeat/  We have a table with 80-100 rows, but each row has around 16 data binds....and the performance was miserable. We too had a requirement to show all of the data and support filtering and sorting, and ended up writing a custom repeater that used lodash templates and cached them. Our data was read only. If I had needed to keep the binds in place I would have had to resort to not showing all of it at once.

Comment: Would it be possible to just use one model for the entire table?  Angular can easily handle rendering all the html at once instead of watching every single cell.

Comment: Not a solution but maybe still interesting for you eventually: have a look at React: http://facebook.github.io/react/index.html

Comment: A few resources: https://github.com/btford/brian-talks-about-angular-with-lots-of-data https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce http://binarymuse.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/

Comment: @aet Your demo appears to be broken in firefox & chrome, {{}} not loading.

Comment: @cheekybastard that is not mine, was just pointing it out, as that seemed like an alternative to ng-repeat that could work very well on a large data set (as long as virtual scrolling is ok). I have not made mine available - although I could if anyone wanted it. The drawback is you have to use lodash templates and you lose out on some 2 way binding. It was so customized to my use case I was not sure it would be applicable to many other people.

Comment: I emailed kamilkp about the angular-vs-repeat demo problems and he said he thinks the issues had been fixed in latest master but the demo page had just not been updated. So he updated it and it should be working again!